# Why is my alternate version of a JavaScript Definitive Guide class example not working

Tags: javascript

Its on pp 200-201 of Chapter 9 on Classes and Modules.  This approach below occured to me as being more straightforward, but the commented output lines below  are not working for unknown reasons:

```
Range.prototype = {
  includes: function(x) {
    return this.from <= x && x <= this.to;
  },

  foreach: function(f) {
    for (var x = Math.ceil(this.from); x <= this.to; x++) f(x);
  },

  toString: function() {
    return "(" + this.from + "..." + this.to + ")";
  },

  Z: "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",    
}

function Range(from,to) {
  this.from = from
  this.to = to
}

var r = new Range(1,3)

console.log(Range.prototype.Z)
console.log(r.constructor.prototype.Z)  //undefined 
console.log(r.Z)
console.log(r.includes(2));
console.log(r.toString());
console.log(r);  // Does not use Range.toString 
r.foreach(console.log); // TypeError
```

Comment: Nitpick, the `function Range` should come before your define the prototype.

Comment: All declarations are hoisted so it doesn't make a difference, right?  (But for style reasons - OK)

Comment: Do you get the same results (I'm in Chrome)

Comment: Not an answer as such, but that last line works with alert, so is console.log not a true function?  It's what they used in the example.  But the other two errors though, why is the Range version of toString not being used, and why is r.constructor.prototype.Z undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `console.log(r.constructor.prototype.Z)  //undefined`

The issue is that `r.constructor === Object` rather than `Range`. This is because the value is inherited from the `prototype` object, which itself has a `constructor` of `Object`.

You'll have to override it within the prototype for it to reference `Range` as you expected:

```
Range.prototype = {
  constructor: Range,
  ...
}
```

[**Edit**] Or, rather than setting the entire `prototype` to a new object, you can extend the existing object:

```
Range.prototype.includes = function ...;
Range.prototype.foreach = function ...;
Range.prototype.toString = function ...;
Range.prototype.Z = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
```

With this, any preset keys, like `constructor`, are still part of the `prototype` without having to set them yourself.

---

2) `console.log(r);  // Does not use Range.toString`

The console simply doesn't use `toString()`. It instead lists the instance as browsable so you can see all of its properties and their values.

If you want it to show the result of `toString()`, you have to call it yourself as you did on the line before:

```
console.log(r.toString());
```

---

3) `r.foreach(console.log); // TypeError`

`log` specifically needs its context (the value of `this`) to be `console`, but it's being passed as a simple function reference without a context.

You'll either have to wrap it in another function so it can be called as a method or [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it to `console`:

```
r.foreach(function (n) { console.log(n); });
r.foreach(console.log.bind(console));
```

Comment: Thanks - is there anything wrong with the basic approach I'm using here - is it not equivalent to what they're doing.

Comment: @Mark I actually don't have the book, so not sure on the comparison. But, aside from the stylistic issue of depending on hoisting that [epascarello already mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420597/why-is-my-alternate-version-of-a-javascript-definitive-guide-class-example-not-w/11421017#comment15064273_11420597), it appears to me to be fine.

Comment: @Mark Actually, there is possible a better way to define prototype properties/methods. See my edit to #1.